# pass unigue_ptr as shared_ptr into a vector

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

Here is a test to understand more about `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr`:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int> > vec_ptr;

int* get()
  {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
    vec_ptr.push_back(std::make_unique<int>());
    }
  return vec_ptr.back().get();
  }
int main()
  {
  int obj = 5;
  int* ptr = get();
  ptr = &obj;

  std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
  std::cout << *vec_ptr[0].get() << std::endl; //expect: 5, but it is 0
  }
```

Apparently nothing is assigned to the `vec_ptr`. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: What is it that you trying to achieve and how does that differ from the observed results?

Comment: there's no assignment to any element of vec_ptr.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you wanted to do:

```
*ptr = obj;
```

instead of

```
ptr = &obj;
```

The former copies the integer `obj` into the space pointed to by `ptr`. The latter (which you're doing) re-points `ptr` to point at `obj`.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, I was thinking that get return a kind of reference pointer

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you have in this program:

- `vec_ptr` contains 3 elements, each of them is 0.
- `obj`, with a value of 5.
- `ptr`, which points to `obj`.

So the program prints the correct values of 5 and 0. If you want to change the value of one of the pointers, then you should assign it like this:

```
*ptr = obj;
```

Then, `ptr` will point to the last element of `vec_ptr` (as returned by `get()`), which will have the value of 5. However, your last line will still print 0, because that prints the first element of the vector, not the last.